# Bootstrap slider - jQuery cant find the active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i need to modify the Bootstrap slider a little bit.

Now i have following HTML Code, together with the jQuery:

```
            <div id="carousel-slider2" class="carousel slide bs-docs-carousel-example">
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li class="rooms active" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="0"></li>
                    <li class="rooms" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li class="rooms" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    <li class="rooms" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                    <li class="rooms" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="4"></li>

                    <li class="ambience" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="5"></li>
                    <li class="ambience" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="6"></li>
                    <li class="ambience" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="7"></li>
                    <li class="ambience" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="8"></li>
                    <li class="ambience" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="9"></li>
                    <li class="ambience" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="10"></li>

                    <li class="holmen" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="11"></li>
                    <li class="holmen" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="12"></li>
                    <li class="holmen" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="13"></li>
                    <li class="holmen" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="14"></li>
                    <li class="holmen" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="15"></li>
                    <li class="holmen" data-target="#carousel-slider2" data-slide-to="16"></li>
                </ol>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#carousel-slider2').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
    console.log($("#carousel-slider2").children(".carousel-indicators").children("li"));
}
```

This works so far, not a problem, i get all the li objects from the . But i just want the one which has the class "active". But for some reason, nothing works, not the native JS method ".getElementsByClassName" nor any jQuery method i know. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
// Get the li element with the active class
var $li = $("#carousel-slider2").children(".carousel-indicators").children("li.active");
```

Or,

```
var $li = $("#carousel-slider2 > .carousel-indicators > li.active");
```

Comment: I already tried that, but if i output this in the console, i get an empty jQuery object.

Comment: @YUNOWORK: This seems to be working [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8zyRu/). See the `$li.length` is coming as 1 in the console, hence the object is not empty.

Comment: In fiddle it does, yeah, but not in my html file. Do i have any HTML-Errors?

Comment: I think there's no error in HTML markup as I have just copy pasted the same thing in the fiddle too..

Answer (score 0):

Use `.find()` method as it allows to search through the descendants of elements in the DOM tree whereas `.children()` method only travels a single level down the DOM tree.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#carousel-slider2').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() { //you havent specified any event
var $li = $("#carousel-slider2").find(".carousel-indicators li.active");
}); //here you made an error in your code
```

});

Comment: Dunno, this doesnt work either ... do i have any errors in my html? Because obv. the jQuery isnt the problem.

Comment: i guess you have not used `.ready()` function.Check my updated code.

Comment: I got the error you haven't specified any `event` for `on` method.

Comment: Okay, and which event do i need here? Im not rly familiar with jQuery and only know the basics tbh.

Comment: Fiddle your entire code..May be you can use `click` event there.

Comment: Okay, i added it as is, but still didnt work as it should. I just looked at the bootstrap-homepage again and found this code, according to them, i've used it correctly:  ---- $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
  // do something…
}) ---- Src: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel

Comment: Okay, nvm, i found the problem: If i slide, the Bootstrap-Slider removes the active class from the element, so jQuery cant find it. When the slide is done, the active class is set new to the new element. So i had to use the other event-handler which fires after the slide, not the one which fires before. Still thank you so much for your help and patience.

Comment: Check my updated answer, i guess that is event what you are talking about.

Comment: Jup, that was it, found it out in the meantime. :)